# Dynamically adding Table data and table rows to HTML, TD not displaying in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform, html-table

I am stuck. I am retrieving data from parse.com and trying to dynamically add them to their respective fields. What am I messing up on? I can console.log the data, so my get request is working. Thank you.

```
var parseData = function() {

    var orderform = Parse.Object.extend("OrderForm");
    var query = new Parse.Query(orderform);
    query.find({
        success: function (results) {

            var tableRow = $('<tr />', {class: 'tableRows'});
          var restaurantListP = [];
            var tdId = [];
            var tdEmail = [];
            var tdMenuItems = [];
            var tdNotes = [];
            var tdPhoneNumber = [];
            var table = $('#orderTable > tbody');

            function newRow($table, cols){
                $row = $('<tr/>');
                for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
                    $col = $('<td/>');
                    $col.append(cols[i]);
                    $row.append($col[i]);
                }
                table.append($row);
            }

            results.forEach(function (r, i) {
               // tdId = $('<td />', { "id": r.id });
                tdEmail = $('<td />', {email_address: r.attributes.email_address });
                tdMenuItems = $('<td />', {menu_items: r.attributes.menu_items });
                tdNotes = $('<td />', {notes: r.attributes.notes});
                tdPhoneNumber = $('<td />', {phone_number: r.attributes.phone_number});

                newRow(table,[tdId,tdEmail,tdMenuItems,tdNotes,tdPhoneNumber]);
               // $('#orderTable > tbody').append(tableRow).append(restaurantListP[0]);

                console.log(tdMenuItems);
                console.log(tdEmail);
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DaveDH2/tb6d7w81/

Comment: in jsfiddle you can include ressources on the left "external ressources" copy paste the link an click on the "+" icon

Comment: In your table `tbody` has `id=orderTable`, & you are trying to get `var table = $('#orderTable > tbody');` which won't give anything, say this `var table = $('#orderTable');` & let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major errors:

1. `id="orderTable"` is set for `<tbody>`, not to `<table>`, so `$('#orderTable > tbody')` finds nothing. You should either move `id="orderTable"` to `<table>`, or rewrite selector to `var table = $('#orderTable')`.
2. `newRow` function works incorrectly: it wraps already created `<td>` with another `<td>`, making `<tr>` html code incorrect. This function should be rewritten in something like this:

   ```
   function newRow($table, cols)
   {
       var $row = $('<tr/>');
       for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++)
       {
           $row.append(cols[i]);
       }
       $table.append($row);
   }
   ```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tb6d7w81/5/).